# Jmeter, login once to use cookie and run other request multiple time

Tags: jmeter

I have a request where I need to login once and then run multiple other request afterwards.
The login would save cookie but this is not working when using setup thread or different thread.

Only if the login and the other scripts are in the same thread group, it will work.

I have a login, other request and HTTP cookie manager in one request.

I want login to run once and run the other request multiple time.

I tried, setup thread but this is not working.
Tried beanshell preprocessor and post processor as well but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

1. The easiest is placing the "login" request(s) under the [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller), this way the requests will be executed only during 1st iteration of the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. Second option is placing the request(s) you need to run "multiple times" under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and specify the number of "times" there
3. And finally if your criteria are more complex instead of Once Only Controller you can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) and specify the function or variable which will control when the "login" will be executed there.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I put the login under Once Only Controller, it loops according the number of thread I set.

Now, If I put the the request that needs to run multiple times in a loop Controller, it wont be a load test since it will run one by one, am I right?

If controller also not working.

Thanks

Comment: It helps to amend your question instead of adding new questions and/or comments as answers, which is unhelpful.